# In Drupal 6, how can a function that builds a multi-page form see the results of the validate function?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

In Drupal 6.20 I'm building a function that creates a multi-page form (my_form_process). On one page the user can select from a list of previously created addresses, or create a new one. If the user wants to create a new one, I use javascript & CSS to hide the selections and unhide the address form (address, city state zip, etc). To make sure the user provides the required data, I have a validate function (my_form_process_validate) that I set the error if the fields are blank. The trouble is that when the pages fails the validation, the my_form_process redraws the form with the validation errors, but defaults back to the "select from a list of previously created addresses", and the "create new" form elements with the errors is still hidden.

How can I tell the my_form_process that builds the form, when the validation has failed show the "create new" div, and hide the "select old" div? I've tried setting a $form['storage'] variable but the my_form_process doesn't seem to see it.

---

Here is some more info:

I tried adding a $form_state['validation_status'] = 'error' in the validation routine but still found that value not in the $form_state array used in the form function when an error was found.

However, when there was no error, the value was available. (a clue)

So, just for kicks, I removed the "form_set_error" line from the validation routine and now the value is available.

So now, I have to set

```
$form_state['validation_error'] = '<ol>'; 
$form_state['validation_status'] = 'error'; 
$form_state['validation_error'] .= '<li>' . t('address cannot be blank') . '</li>';
$form_state['validation_error'] .= '</ol>';
```

Then in the form function I can test the $form_state['validation_error'] and if 'error' then use

```
drupal_set_message($form_state['validation_error'],$form_state['validation_status']);
```

To display the message and then set the display property of the div's appropriately.

Sure seems like a bug in the "form_set_error" process, but I'm a newbie in Drupal/PHP land so I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass values through the $form_state variable back and forth between the form function, validation function, and submit handler functions. This might help (if you haven't looked at this already) http://drupal.org/node/144132#multistep

Comment: Thanks for the link Shane - it helped some. I think I figured it out by trying out some other options. I'll share them below.

Comment: posted my approach as an edit in the message body to maintain the unanswered status.